# Google Map showing Blank Screen

Tags: android-maps-v2

I am currently developing an android app that needs google maps. All of the instructions and procedures are done and working perfectly but when I run it now it displays only blankscreen and zoom.

This is my main `activity.java`:

```
package com.example.lrt;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class Googlemapko extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.googlemapko);
    SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content,     fragment).commit();

}
}
```

This is my Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.lrt.Googlemapko" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MY Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.lrt"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >


  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />



<permission android:name="com.example.lrt.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
   android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.lrt.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

 <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" 
    android:required="true"/>
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB61vojABlTFrB9QTv9kXWKXPknI0iot_o" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    
    
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.lrt.Googlemapko"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to run signed app or not?
If not, you just will not be able to connect to maps api, so it will show you blank fragnent.